# Looking for a novel in which a super soldier sneaks away from home country/planet to fight, but where he ends up is not like what he was expecting

Tags: story-identification

The novel may have a test tube on the cover with a man in it, or a cloning tube with a man being "grown" in it.

It might be from the 1990s.

The story starts off with a man in a college type environment.

I remember two events that happen in the beginning and one near the end.

First he waylays a "fertile" coed on her way to class and has sex with her in the bushes outside the classroom. Due to his pheromones or great looks she is not upset about this, more annoyed that he tore her panties/pantyhose.

Later while in gym class (hand to hand combat type lectures) he was bored and paying more attention to the girls in the gym instead of listening to the trainer/instructor. The instructor chastises him, and he responds, "Fine I will take you on coach, show you what I know." In the ensuing match, his superior physical condition and skill allows him to kill the instructor.

After graduation his class will be boarding ships to another planet/country where they will infiltrate the enemy. I am pretty sure they were not immediately going to war.

Maybe due to his killing the coach (the faculty are only annoyed he killed the coach, he is NOT in trouble) he is called to the head office for a stern lecture, but over hears them talking about him after he leaves.

Basically he is their glorified Super Lab Rat. The best of all the students. (Smart, knowledgeable, powerful.) The other students who are only average(?) will be sent off to the ships to their destinations, but he will be kept back and told he is to "teach" when actually they are really only keeping him there to breed many more women. His offspring should inherit his qualities.

Well he does not like this, he wants to prove himself in battle, so sneaks onto one of the ships. IIRC the others students go through briefings on their destinations or missions. Since he does not get the briefing and is clueless about what to do when he arrives, he more or less starts screwing every "fertile" woman he can find.

Near the end of the story he is hiding out with a jealous woman. I am pretty sure she was infertile.  While he can do it with her, he gets no joy out of doing it with her so he sneaks some sex with another woman. The infertile woman finds out and in a rage, she cuts half of his dick off.

Comment: Super solder is what you use for super electrical work.

Comment: Hmmm.  [Ender's Game](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender%27s_Game) meets [Lorena Bobbit.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_and_Lorena_Bobbitt)  Are you sure it wasn't a short story in Playboy or Penthouse?

Comment: @JRE Nope. It was a novel. Its possible it might have been from the late 80s, But I think it was early 90s.

Comment: @NJohnny:  I was joking.  The mashup of super soldier (*Ender's Game,*) loads of sex (teenage fantasy) and penis whacking just sort of spontaneously suggested a Playboy scifi parody in my mind.

Comment: I bet if this is answered it turns out to have been published by Baen.

Comment: @Shawn - Tor, apparently.  But there is some connection between Tor and Baen....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect this is Jim Morris' *Breeder* (1988). Not Baen, but Tor. The cover is a match with the test tube and the story is a match for the heavy sex.

[image: cover]

From the back of the [book](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6678257-breeder?from_search=true&from_srp=true&qid=IzO1eEWNKg&rank=1):

> Jeff Clendenning was a science project, the perfect badass hero who could kill any man, and replicate himself by seducing and impregnating any woman he wanted. He was a breeder…but he didn’t know it. He was supposed to stay in the Potemkin village lab he was born into, not thrust into a guerrilla war--an America torn by civil disobedience. And there he was, released into a world of avid fertile women. The results were fun for a while, but then... Well, there are situations where being the perfect adventure hero will not help you.

Comment: Yes, Pretty sure this is it. The cover is familiar, and the description a good match.